# Widget distance modifyed on different screen device

Tags: android, android-layout

I've read the android support multiple screen tutorial. 
when i try to see how my layout fit on different screen, something gone wrong. In my case i have only one tipe of image (970x174) for test copyed into all drawable folder. 
By see my layout on different screen, in most cases, layout is not as i would. I paste code of my layout (that it fits well into nexus 4 screens)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/TEMPORARY"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe i should do a different density image for each screen type?

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout doesn't have a orientation tag, so remove it.

Since you put the same image on all the drawable types, the image will have a fixed pixel size, which will decrease the size of the image on the screen as the screen density increases. But you used dp as unit on the layout, so the 128dp will increase in size as the density increases, to make the size on screen appear the same on different devices.

So if you want to have the same layout with the same size on screen regardless of screen density, delete the other copies of the image and leave only one drawable folder, and android will handle scaling for you on different screen density phones.

Comment: if i delete one or more folder, when i test my layout on different screen, some screen looks empty, and only screen corresponding to drawable density folder leaved, is showed

Comment: Did you try using only a drawable/ folder, maybe your using a too restrict qualifier, more info on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility

Comment: Have you tried adding a scale type on the image view, like android:scaleType="fitXY"